# Selenium | Loading multiple extensions into Selenium's ChromeDriver, only receiving the last defined

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome-extension, selenium-chromedriver

I'm currently attempting to load two extensions into Selenium's ChromeDriver. Ublock Origin and Ghostery. Looking online, the solution for this tends to just be as simple as adding an argument for each extension. However, when I attempt to add these two arguments, it will only load the second defined extension and ignore the first.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"

ublock = r'C:\Users\Senuvox\PycharmProjects\Projects\SeleniumExtensions\1.35.2_0'
ghostery = r'C:\Users\Senuvox\PycharmProjects\Projects\SeleniumExtensions\8.5.5_0'

options = Options()
options.add_argument('load-extension=' + ghostery)
options.add_argument('load-extension=' + ublock)
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors=yes')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, options=options)
driver.create_options()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
```

When one runs this script, as stated before, only Ublock will load into the Selenium chrome browser. Similarly, if I swap the order so Ublock is first and Ghostery is second, only Ghostery will load.

Additionally I have attempted to one-line it by adding commas in-between the two extension variables. Unfortunately, this provides an error as add_argument takes only two positional arguments.

Any insights on how I might solve this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not familiar with this `driver.create_options()` and I can't find any docs on it. What does it do? I thought `driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, options=options)` is all you need to set the options.

Comment: Also, can you help me find the SeleniumExtensions you are using so I can download and replicate your code?

Answer (score 1):

```
#use .crx file path of extension
options.add_extension('C:\\Users\\ublock-1.35.2_0.crx')
options.add_extension('C:\\Users\\ghostery-8.5.5_0.crx')
```

[useful resource](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/using-extensions-with-selenium-and-python)